# Oracle11G: Clustering issue?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm creating a cluster for the table CUSTOMER & PURCHASE. I have done all necessary steps.
Then how to assign cluster and view the clustered table?

This is a cluster

```
SQL> create cluster cust_pur_cluster (cust_id integer);
```

This is index for cluster

```
SQL> create index cust_pur_idx on cluster cust_pur_cluster;
```

This is the PURCHASE table definition & Assign cluster

```
SQL> create table purchase(bill_no integer primary key,
  2  bill_no integer,
  3  cust_id integer,
  4  prod_name varchar(10) not null,
  5  quanity integer not null,
  6  rate_per_unit number(6,2),
  7  cluster cust_pur_cluster(cust_id);
```

This is the CUSTOMER table definition & Assign cluster

```
SQL>create table customer(
2 cust_id  integer,
3 cust_name varchar(10),
4 cust_address varchar(50))
5 cluster cust_pur_cluster(cust_id);
```

Table Data

```
 TABLE: CUSTOMER
cust_id   cust_name    cust_address  
------------------------------------
1          Esmael         Jima           
2          Munira         Gera          
3          Jemila1        Addis     
4          Ahmed          Agaro        
5          Amina          Agaro 



TABLE: PURCHASE
    bill_no    cust_id    prod_name    quantity    rate_per_unit  
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    1001       1           soap         5              $10            
    1002       3           Omo          2              $15        
    1003       1           Perfume      1              $52
    1004       2           Socks        3              $7
    1005       1           Tooth Brush  2              $5
```

Comment: You don't select from a cluster, you select from the table. Using a cluster is just a way to define a *physical storage layout*. Something that the client does not and should not know anything about.

Comment: Thanks dear, can you help me how to use and select from cluster?

Comment: The question does not make sense. You do not "select from a cluster" - you select from a table using `select ... from table_name`

Comment: If you understand what I want to do and you know the problem. Then tell me what will be the right way?

Comment: Thanks! but I found misconception from you. Previously i already done cluster with single table. like above query & it works fine. This is two table and already the cluster object is assigned for such you said tables. So the help is not successful try and see the detail carefully.